# I need help getting a form to send an email with the results

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm building my company website and I've run into a problem.  I used to be decent at php and html but I haven't used code in a couple of years.  I have created a form for customers to input their information, and I want to send it to mail.php for the results to be emailed to me.  I seem to be having trouble with the mail.php side for some reason.  I have attached the form code from my main screen and the mail.php page.  Every time I test this, I get a "the page could not complete the task" message when mail.php loads.  From everything I've read, this seems to be the correct way to do this, so I'm sorry if it's just a simple syntax error.  Could someone please explain to me what I'm doing wrong? Or even just point me in the right direction of where I could research how to fix this?

Form side on main page

```
    <form action="mail.php" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
          <h3 class="titlenext">Contact us</h3>
          <div class="input-container">
            <input name="name" class="input" />
            <label for="">Name</label>
            <span>Name</span>
          </div>
          <div class="input-container">
            <input type="email" name="email" class="input" />
            <label for="">Email</label>
            <span>Email</span>
          </div>
          <div class="input-container">
            <input type="tel" name="phone" class="input" />
            <label for="">Phone</label>
            <span>Phone</span>
          </div>
          <div class="input-container">
            <input name="address" class="input" />
            <label for="">Address</label>
            <span>Address</span>
          </div>
          <div class="input-container textarea">
            <textarea name="message" class="input"></textarea>
            <label for="">Pest Issues</label>
            <span>Pest Issues</span>
          </div>
          <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn" />
        </form>
```

My mail.php code

```
    <?php
    
    if (!$_POST) {
    redirect('https://domain.tld');
    }
    
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $goto = "info@pandppest.com";

    $subject = "Website Lead";
    $content = "Name: " . $name . "\n";
    $content = "Email: " . $email . "\n";
    $content = "Phone: " . $phone . "\n";
    $content = "Address: " . $address . "\n";
    $content = "Message: " . $message . "\n";

    mail($goto, $subject, $content);
    redirect('index.html');

    ?>
```

Comment: `the page could not complete the task` is a strange error to see. Have you checked your server's logs or enabled php errors/warnings? If you var_dump($_POST) at the top of mail.php and then die immediately what happnes?

Comment: So I'm actually getting error code HTTP ERROR 500.

Comment: It's giving me this:

Comment: This page isn’t workingwww.pandppest.com is currently unable to handle this request.  I blocked out all code for the emails and tried just echo Name: {$name}";
  And it still gave me the same error code, so now I think it may be a problem with the POST from my main page not sending the variables?  Sorry for making this 3 comments, I keep pressing enter by accident.